# How to reuse a mvc app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture

I've created a web app (mvc4) that I'd like to reuse in multiple projects. The site is an admin panel, but it may be extended and slightly modified in each project. I want to avoid copying the project over, because I'd like to be able to update each project to the latest version at the lowest possible cost.

So far I have tried 2 approaches:

- a script that 'clones' the project by copying all the necessary things as well as altering others (guids in assemblies, namespaces and things like that) - this works fine for extensibility and modification, but that's just a copy so pushing 'updates' is a mess (I did it manually) and it does not scale.
- portable areas from mvc contrib project - this seemed like a good idea at first, but it turns out that it's nice for simple scenarios, but fails at more advanced use cases. It doesn't support localization (from resources embedded in the portable area), bundling and min requires a lot of hacks (mvc contrib is still on mvc 3), it's not possible (out of the box) to reuse shared views or Display/Editor templates from the portable area and it looks like if I'd go further that way, some new things would come up

Currently I'm thinking about 'just' branching each project from the core one. This would of course require the same changes (or at least a big subset of them) that were done in the script I mentioned earlier, and I'm afraid that if I try to pull updates from the core project the number of conflicts will render the whole approach unusable.

Does anyone have an idea on how I could tackle this problem?

Comment: Have you considered using Nuget? You'd have to be careful to avoid new versions overwriting changes in the consumer projects, but nuget is definitely worth a look.

Comment: Yes I have, but it does not satisfy all the requirements. Doing updates in modified files will be a frequent case and if a file was modified, nuget skips the override

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to create a NuGet package of the mvc app and reuse it. So versioning and applying updates would be much easier. However it takes a bit work to make your code completely isolated from the codes you want to add in the new project.